# Is std::future::wait a memory barrier? (I can not explain this data race)

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

Here is the code:

```
std::vector<bool> a(req_count_);
std::vector<std::future<void>> waits(req_count_);

for (int i = 0; i < req_count_; i++) {
  // send into a threadpool implementation
  waits[i] = framework::Async([i, &a] {
    a[i] = true; // write true
  });
}

for (int i = 0; i < req_count_; i++) {
  waits[i].wait(); // memory barrier?
}

int last_req_count = req_count_;
req_count_ = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < last_req_count; i++) {
  if (!a[i]) { // read false
    return false;
  }
}
```

My question is does `std::future::wait` serves as a memory barrier? `std::future::wait` waits for the function call to complete, but does the function **happens before** `std::future::wait` (e.g., does the state mutation caused by the function call visible from other threads)?

If `std::future::wait` does not serves as a memory barrier, how can we implement the threadpool so that a memory barrier is triggered automatically when the future completes?

Please correct me if you think my understanding of memory barrier is wrong.

Comment: I have always assumed that it is a memory barrier (fence) since it could not guarantee consistency otherwise. However, it does not explicitly say so in the documentation, which is probably a deficiency of the documentation. See the docs on std::promise, which do mention how the mutex works: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/promise/set_value

Comment: Thanks @RichardHodges ! I am assuming it is a memory barrier too. But the data race is gone if I use a lock to protect variable `a`. Maybe `future::wait` just ensures the value returned from `future::get` is valid?
 (trying to justify the possibility that it is not a memory barrier).

Comment: From the C++17 standard:

_Calls to functions that successfully set the stored result of a shared state synchronize with (4.7) calls to
functions successfully detecting the ready state resulting from that setting. The storage of the result (whether
normal or exceptional) into the shared state synchronizes with (4.7) the successful return from a call to a
waiting function on the shared state._

I suspect your issue is not with the wait call itself.

Comment: if you need to communicate across threads without locks, you need to use the `<atomic>` header

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> **[container.requirements.dataraces]/2** Notwithstanding **[res.on.data.races]**, implementations are required to avoid data races when the contents of the contained object in different elements in the same container, **excepting `vector<bool>`**, are modified concurrently.
>
> **[container.requirements.dataraces]/3** [ *Note:* For a `vector<int> x` with a size greater than one, `x[1] = 5` and `*x.begin() = 10` can be executed concurrently without a data race, but `x[0] = 5` and `*x.begin() = 10` executed concurrently may result in a data race. As an exception to the general rule, for a `vector<bool> y`, `y[0] = true` may race with `y[1] = true`. *—end note* ]

Emphasis mine. The race happens in `a[i] = true;`. `vector<bool>` is not a real container, accessing an "element" requires bit manipulations that touch neighboring elements.